# JQuery - cloning datepicker and select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I asked a similar question yesterday, but after a few additions, things seem to have gone pear shaped.  I have some HTML which takes the following form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="actionTable">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr id='actionRow1'>
                        <td>
                          <input type="text" name='actionInput[0][action]' id="actionInput"  placeholder='Action' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <select class="responsibility" name='actionInput[0][responsibility]' id="responsibilityInput">
                                <option value="One">One</option>
                                <option value="Two">Two</option>
                                <option value="Three">Three</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="text" name='actionInput[0][deliveryDate]' id="dateInput" placeholder='Completion Date' class="form-control dateControl"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Add Row</a>
                <a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So it has a text input, a select, and another text for the date.  The names for the input are a 2D array because I need to handle this data in a specific way later.

Anyways, when an Add Row button is clicked, it should clone the whole tr.  This includes destroying the select2 and datepicker, as well as updating the names and id's of the new inputs. To do this, I have the following JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#add_row').on('click', function(evt){addRow();});
    $('#delete_row').on('click', function(evt){deleteRow();});
});

function addRow() {

    $("table tr#actionRow1").eq(0).clone().each(function(tr_idx, tr_elem) {

        $(".dateControl").datepicker("destroy");

        $(".responsibility").select2("destroy");

        var
            $tr = $(tr_elem),
            newRowIdx = $("table tr").length;

        $tr.attr('id', 'actionRow' + newRowIdx);

        $tr.find("input, select").each(function(i_idx, i_elem) {

            var $input = $(i_elem);

            if($input.attr('id') == 'actionInput') {
                $(this).val("");
            }

            if ($input.hasClass('dateControl')) {
                $(this).val("");
            }

            $input.attr({
                'id': function(_, id) {
                    return id + newRowIdx;
                },
                'name': function(_, id) {
                    return id.replace('[0]', '['+ newRowIdx +']');
                },
                'value': ''
            });
        });

        $(".dateControl").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        });

        $(".responsibility").select2({
            tags: true
        });

    }).appendTo("table");
}

function deleteRow() {
    curRowIdx = $("table tr").length;
    if (curRowIdx > 1) {
        $("#actionRow" + (curRowIdx - 1)).remove();
        curRowIdx--;
    }
}
```

I have set up the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqugd7vL/15/) to demonstrate.

In the Fiddle, I have had to comment out the destroy methods otherwise it throws an error.  First problem, on first visit, the datepicker and select2 are not working.  When you click Add Row, the previous rows datepicker and select2 then works, but the new one does not.  So it is sort of delayed.
Once you start adding multiple rows, it decides to add multiple select boxes in some of the rows.  Not too sure why this is happening.

Any advice in sorting this out much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello Nick, for your datepicker & select not working at the beginning the reason is the fact that you are not initializing them. See added block: https://jsfiddle.net/fqugd7vL/16/

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.  Do you know why the destroying of cloned datepickers and selects do not work?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$(".dateControl").datepicker();` will attempt to initialise a datepicker widget on all elements matching `".dateControl"` currently in the DOM. Thus on the first click you'd initialise it on the first row (but NOT on the one you're cloning, since it hasn't been appended yet!). The third row added then re-initialises the datepicker on the first row and initialises it on the second, etc. Same for the other widget. You should restrict the matcher to only the row you're currently working on:

```
$(".dateControl", $tr).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});

$(".responsibility", $tr).select2({
  tags: true
});
```

You don't need the `destroy` calls at all if you do this. Also, make sure you call these for the first row explicitly (see NicolasR's comment)

---

Also, the datepicker creates a new `table` element, so you need to target your own table everywhere you use the table selector. Otherwise the `addRow` function will stop working correctly after the first time you open a datepicker (which is when the new table is appended to the DOM, and the `"table"` selector in the `appendTo` line starts matching it): https://jsfiddle.net/r94pkLLb/3/

Comment: Thank you for your input.  It still seems to act very strange though https://jsfiddle.net/fqugd7vL/17/

Comment: Strange yes. Why don't you set your line programmatically in a function, and even use it to create your first row?

Comment: @NickPrice This is the only real problem in your code, the rest is just DOM data and metadata getting carried over from bad clones. Just clean it up a bit, add a proper placeholder, and it will work. I was assuming all those bits got mixed in while you were editing your code to fit SO's format. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r94pkLLb/1/

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful.  I had one last thing I cant seem to figure out.  When you add a new row, the id changes e.g. actionRow1.  This works fine to begin with, it increments without problem.  If you add a few rows however, and then give some input, the id of the row jumps drastically.  This then means that the delete no longer works.  I can't figure out why this happens.  Do you have any idea why?  Thanks

Comment: p.s. it appears to be the date input that causes the jump

Comment: May have figured it out, datepicker has its own table so I need to target mine via the id https://jsfiddle.net/r94pkLLb/2/

Comment: Maybe not - it even appears that your version doesnt work with datepicker after a few clones